# Read a CSV file column-wise

Tags: python, file, csv

I have this csv file like following: 
[image]

and I now only know how to read it in row order. This is what I wrote:

```
import csv
enrollments=[]

f=open('D911_Leistung.csv','rb')
reader=csv.reader(f)

for row in reader:
    enrollments.append(row)

f.close()

print(enrollments[0])
```

and what shows up is a single row:[image]

I want to split the data of every channel, is there a way to realize it?

Comment: `for column in row` would be a good start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pandas` function [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('D911_Leistung.csv', sep=';')
```

This creates a `DataFrame`. In general, `pandas` is a really powerful library for handling structured data. If you are new to programming in Python, `pandas` is a great library to learn imho.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a pure-python approach, you can put each row's item into its own separate list (transposing as the data is read).

(Tested on python2)

```
import csv
with open('D911_Leistung.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)     

    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i == 0: 
            data = [[] for _ in range(len(row))]

        for j, col in enumerate(row):
            data[j].append(col)
```

---

You can also load your data with `numpy` and then transpose it.

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('my_file.csv', delimiter=';').T
```

Comment: From the screenshot it is apparent that `delimiter` should be `';'`. Now the CSV reader just reads each line as one column because it misses the commas.

Comment: @9000 Thanks! I missed that.

Comment: I try your way but it seems like the file is way to big and it just get stuck all the time....

Comment: @YingqiangGao I added a pure-py approach.

Comment: sorry what does pure-py approach mean? new to programming don't understand that...

Comment: @YingqiangGao I added another way to do it without numpy (pure-py = vanilla python).

Comment: @YingqiangGao Sorry. Couple of bugs. Fixed and tested on python2.

Comment: Thx a lot for your nice response :)